# How can I call a javascript function from an html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `.js` file defined as follows:

```
<script>
    function sayHello() {
        alert("Hello World");
    }
</script>
```

And I have a `.html` file defined as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/testCSS.css">
        <title>test html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/testJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I call the `sayHello()` function?

Comment: The .js file should not have any `script` tags

Answer (score 1):

script.js

```
function sayHello() {
    alert("Hello World");
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script>
            sayHello();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call it!

let me explain in an example.
let's say you have a button in that html that calls sayHello function.

`<button type="button" onclick="sayHello ()">Say hello</button>`

I think you should take a look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Jus replace the link to script with content of .Js file...

Or call the function

```
     <script>
       sayHello()
     </script>
```